Gibberish text when using Ubuntu Interface Font in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
After updating from 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS (and possibly some tweaking of default Ubuntu font to increase its weight -- I don't remember!), I got the problem with font rendering of "Ubuntu" font.
According to gnome-tweaks, "Ubuntu" is set as default font:

The system however renders gibberish text in certain situations: for instance, in firefox address bar suggestions:

Here is the intro text on chatgpt web-page:

The latter uses "system-ui" font to render that text. When I change Interface Font from "Ubuntu" to "Roboto", all the text is rendered alright.
What could cause Ubuntu font to be rendered gibberish?
